# Adding Categories navigation to show certain entries

Tags: categories, navigation

I'm abit lost as to how to structure my FAQ page.

I have a single FAQ page that pulls in every FAQ post, these posts come from the FAQ Entries channel.

But

On the single FAQ page, how do I add a navigation that only shows certain FAQ Entries using categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand properly, you want to show *related* FAQ based on categories.

On your entry template, you could do something like this:

```
{# Fetch the categories of the current entry #}
{% set entryCategories = entry.yourCategoriesFieldHandle.all() %}

{# Find related entries #}
{% set relatedFaqs = craft.entries()
    .section('faqs')
    .relatedTo(entryCategories)
    .all() %}

{# Display related FAQs #}
<ul>
{% for entry in relatedFaqs %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>   
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Change `yourCategoriesFieldHandle` to what your field handle is and `.section('faqs')` to the correct section handle for your FAQ's section.

Comment: Thank you very much!